# Можно ли установить постоянное соединение по HTTP с IdHttpServer?

Tags: delphi, http

Сейчас у меня есть `IdTcpServer`. В свойстве, которого, я храню объект `AContext.Data := myObject`. А в событии `IdTcpServerDisconnect` я прописал `AContext.Data := nil`.

Я хочу сделать аналогично с `IdHttpServer`, но `Disconnect` происходит после каждого post запроса.

Как настроить `IdHttpServer` так, что бы быть уверенным, что если выполнилось `Disconnect` значит клиент точно отсоединился?

Comment: Можно(почти), смотрите  `connection = KeepAlive`, но так не делают и нет гарантии что браузер захочет работать в таком режиме =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков пробовал, к сожалению не помогло. Смотрю AutoStartSession, может что нибудь даст.

Comment: Я вам сразу написал что это так не работает и то что вам нужно делается иначе

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков как иначе?

Comment: Иначе - что вот прям щас в голову пришло механизм типо сессий, в куках передавать идентификатор в объекта в ассоциативном массиве, а в самом массиве хранить объекты

Comment: Какой-то странный вопрос. Если вызвалось событие `OnDisconnect`, то можете быть уверены, что соединение разорвано (кто бы ни бы инициатором разрыва). Если это событие происходит после каждого запроса, значит клиент не хочет или не умеет держать постоянное соединение. С сервером (если у вас, конечно, актуальная версия Indy) дополнительно ничего делать не надо, настраивайте клиента.